# 2 way delete relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `user_relations` table.

```
user_id | related_user_id
-------------------------
  1     | 15
  1     | 17
  4     | 56
 15     |  1
  5     | 34
```

When I destroy the row `(1 | 15)`, I want rails to automatically delete the parallel row `(15 | 1)`.

Is there a rails way of doing this?

This is the user_relation class:

```
class UserRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :related_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "related_user_id"
end
```

Comment: is `user_relations` a join table?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "join". It is joining the same users table as you can see from the columns user_id and related_user_id.

Comment: do you have any model representing the user_relations? or it is just a database table?

Comment: Could you paste the UserRelations class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write a filter to do so in UserRelation model,

```
after_destroy :delete_associated


def delete_associated 
 ur = UserRelations.find_by_related_user_id_and_user_id(related_user_id, user_id)
 ur.delete if ur
end
```

Update:

To create associated record you can write a filter like this,

```
 after_create :create_associated
 def create_associated
   UserRelations.find_or_create_by_related_user_id_and_user_id(related_user_id, user_id) #check if already exist or create new
 end
```

Comment: It doesn't work!! It generated an endless loop! Because each time it tries to delete it comes to this callback again...

Comment: That's correct, you can use delete instead of destroy to avoid callback. Updated the answer above.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with after_save also? I mean to save a new same object in the after_save callback without having an after_save callback again.

Comment: yes, in the same way you can write a after_save filter. But do check if record is already exist to avoid callback loop.

Comment: Instead of after_save; you can use after_create to avoid call back on every save.

Comment: This is not the difference between after_save and after_create. After_create is being called once when the object is created, and since I do create a new object it will bw called again.

Comment: Yes, in your case it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If it have something like

`has_many: related_users, foreign_key: related_user_id`

You could add `dependent: destroy` and when this row is deleted it will also destroy the user

Comment: I don't want to delete the user, just the connection that was created in this table!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could select both those rows with:

```
result = UserRelation.where(:user_id => [1,15]).where(:related_user_id => [1,15])
```

And then:

```
result.destroy_all
```